# jQuery resizable forces top of the element to be >=0

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-resizable

I have a problem with jQuery resizable.

Have a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eUxZS/1/). Even though containment is set to `#outerContainer`, when I try to drag the `child` (the blue box) by either its lower or upper handle, its top position is forced to be 0, even though it is well within the bounds of the red box.

Any clues?

Here's the code, just in case:

**HTML**

```
<div id='outerContainer'>
    <div id='margin'></div>
    <div id='parent'>
        <div id='child'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#outerContainer {
    position:relative;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#margin {
    height:25px;
}

#parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 50px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#child {
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    width:40px;
    height:50px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('#child').resizable({handles: 'n, s', containment: '#outerContainer', grid: [10, 10]});
```

Answer (score 1):

In CSS, `top: -20px` is considered an **offset** value, which is why you must *relate* it to another element to be able to use it (aka `position: relative / absolute / fixed`)

When you click the resize on its upper border, it has to revert its `top` value to give you a chance to adjust it.  You aren't changing the element's `width` or `height` with that resize, you're moving it to a new position.

Long story short, use `margin-top` instead of `top` and you're golden.

```
#child {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```

### [Demo Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/eUxZS/2/)

Comment: I still don't get it. I know that it's an offset, but what I do not know is why the hell does it **have to** revert its top value to 0? **Especially**, that once you remove the containment it's all jolly good and jquery is happy with negative top offset, which is not an error on it's own, is it?

Comment: But thanks for the margin-top tip, I'll resort to that, if I have to :)